# How to use webdriver wait when we dont know what will be next page(object)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Step 1: Go to url: https://www.charter.com/buyflow/buyflow-localization

Step 2: Enter the addresses and click on Continue button.

```
streetAddress   zipCode
9798 hale dr    63123
1101 Toole Av   59802
1205 Toole Av, apt 3    59802
1098 Mosaic Dr. 76179
```

Step 3: we don’t know what will be the next page , it may one of the following

```
a.  https://www.charter.com/buyflow/multiple-addresses
b.  https://www.charter.com/buyflow/localization-error
c.  https://www.charter.com/buyflow/address-does-not-match
d.  https://www.charter.com/buyflow/address-clarification
e.  https://www.charter.com/buyflow/retrieve-cart-implicit/
f.  https://www.charter.com/buyflow/store-front
```

So after step:2,  I have to wait for next page to load. Currently I am using thread.sleep(); but every time I have to wait for particular amount of time although page is loaded.
So I want to put fluent kind of wait here .
So how can I do it?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

In your case, waiting for *invisibility of the loading panel*, sounds logical to rely on:

```
<div ng-show="loadingPanel.show" class="loading-panel row ng-hide"> 
 <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4"> 
  <img class="large-logo center-block" src="/resources/images/residential/logo-charter.png" alt="loading"> 
  <p class="text-center">LOADING</p> 
  <img class="timer center-block" src="/resources/images/residential/buyflow/loading-time.gif" alt="Charter Spectrum Loading Timer"> 
 </div> 
</div>
```

Example in Python:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".loading-panel"))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I observe, you always get icon LiveChat (after the page is finished loading) regardless what will be the next pages, so I would do this in Java:

```
webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("rnowChatLink_type1")));
```

with the ID from the site

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Alecxe .

In java, try this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);//driver is webdriver
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".panel.panel-primary.panel-unstyled-sm")));
```